# What is second argument in getRequest()->getPost()

Tags: magento-1.9, post-data

What is the use of second argument in `getRequest()->getPost`?

```
$products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products', -1);
$products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products', 1);
$products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument in `getRequest()->getPost` indicates which value to return if there is no variable found with used key value in `$_POST` data.
When you use

```
$products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products', 1);
```

It will return you Post data variable with key `products` if it exists and if its not available it will return you with the second argument.
If you dont pass any second argument like

```
$products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('products');
```

It will return you `null` if key value is not set.
Please refer to `lib\Zend\Controller\Request\Http.php::getPost()`

Answer (score 1):

It's the default value to use if the key is not found in the `$_POST` variable:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a member of the $_POST superglobal
 *
 * If no $key is passed, returns the entire $_POST array.
 *
 * @todo How to retrieve from nested arrays
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed $default Default value to use if key not found
 * @return mixed Returns null if key does not exist
 */
public function getPost($key = null, $default = null)
{
    if (null === $key) {
        return $_POST;
    }

    return (isset($_POST[$key])) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;
}
```